# Sequelize not mapping model attributes into SQL query

Tags: sequelize.js

I've created a new model named `User` and trying to save it into database but query is not completed by sequelize and i can't figure out what is the problem.

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  User.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });
  return User;
};
```

Code for creating a user instance:

```
let user = User.build({name:params.name,password:'sdfasfsaf'});
await user.save();
```

and the query that is generated is below!

```
INSERT INTO "Users" ("id","name","password","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING "id","name","password","createdAt","updatedAt";
```

as you can see, name and password field are not filled in SQL query.

Comment: Have you tried to execute it?

Comment: @Nick what do you mean? generated SQL means the code is executed! –

Comment: Where do you get that query? What the execution prints out?

Comment: @Nick  query is printed in nodejs console. when `await user.save()` is called, this qurey is automatically generated

Comment: I know, i use sequelize, the query it logs on the console never had the values(or at least the default sequelize logger). It just know the values and executes the query with correct values

Comment: @Nick this logger query sholud be a valid query not having $ sign in query, so the values are not mapping to query and it's not inserting row in db

Comment: @Nick you are right man. problem was another place in my code! i thought the query should have real values. thanks bro